# Extract date from text inside html tags using XPATH

Tags: html, xml, xpath, extract

Extract date inside html tag using xpath substring

I have tried using substring in xpath

```
<span id="latestReplyLine"><a href="#comment-965609" class="lastScroll js-latest-reply">Latest reply</a> on May 22, 2019 by John Stoltzfus</span>
```

I am using below xpath query to extract text

```
/span[@id="latestReplyLine"]/text()[substring-after(substring-before(.,' by '), ' on ')]
```

Expected result -

```
"May 22, 2019"
```

But I am getting,

```
"on May 22, 2019 by John Stoltzfus"
```

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing the right string by one space (`on` instead of `on`).
An improved XPath expression is the following:

```
normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(string(/span[@id='latestReplyLine']),'by'), 'on'))
```

This will give you the right result.

Comment: How about `substring(/span,21,14)`?